# Latitudinal/Longitudinal difference in meters between two coordinates?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I'm trying to create an MKCoordinateRegion where the user location is in the center, and another coordinate should be visible within the region. Simply put, I'm trying to center on the user location while having a certain amount of annotations visible. My approach is to look where the N:th farthest away coordinate is located and try to calculate a distance, or coordinate region, to this coordinate form the user location coordinate.

```
    var topLeftCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -90.0, longitude: 180.0)
    var bottomRightCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 90.0, longitude: -180.0)

    topLeftCoord.longitude = fmin(topLeftCoord.longitude, outerLongitude)
    topLeftCoord.latitude = fmax(topLeftCoord.latitude, outerLatitude)
    bottomRightCoord.longitude = fmax(bottomRightCoord.longitude, outerLongitude)
    bottomRightCoord.latitude = fmin(bottomRightCoord.latitude, outerLatitude)

    topLeftCoord.longitude = fmin(topLeftCoord.longitude, userCoordinates.longitude)
    topLeftCoord.latitude = fmax(topLeftCoord.latitude, userCoordinates.latitude)
    bottomRightCoord.longitude = fmax(bottomRightCoord.longitude, userCoordinates.longitude)
    bottomRightCoord.latitude = fmin(bottomRightCoord.latitude, userCoordinates.latitude)

    let regionSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(fabs((topLeftCoord.latitude - bottomRightCoord.latitude)), fabs((bottomRightCoord.longitude - topLeftCoord.longitude)))
    var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: userCoordinates, span: regionSpan)

    region = self.mapView.regionThatFits(region)
    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```

This kind of works, but I get a bit offseted. I believe the issue is that here I do not take into consideration that the user location should be in the center, so this code simply makes sure that the user and the coordinate of `outerLatitude` and `outerLongitude` is within the span. But when centring on the user coordinate the outer coordinate is no longer visible.

I can't for the life of me figure this out. I've also tried doing this way:

```
    let outerLocation = CLLocation(latitude: outerLatitude, longitude: outerLongitude)
    let userLocation = CLLocation(latitude: userCoordinates.latitude, longitude: userCoordinates.longitude)

    let distance = userLocation.distance(from: outerLocation)
    var region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userCoordinates, distance, distance)

    region = self.mapView.regionThatFits(region)
    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```

But I end up with the same result, which I don't understand really. I get a distance which is around 340m (which is pretty reasonable). However `MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance` is asking for `latitudinalMeters` and `longitudinalMeters` where I simply send in the `distance` from coordinate A to B. I can't find a way to split the components into `latitudinalMeters` and `longitudinalMeters`, I can simply get 1 distance between the two.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't find a way to split the components into latitudinalMeters and longitudinalMeters, I can simply get 1 distance between the two

Try creating a new point with the same latitude as your user location and the same longitude as your outer location and use that to get the "latitudinal distance"

Then create a point with the same logitude as the user location and the same latitude as the outer location and use that to get the longitudinal distance.

Note: If the outer point is closer to the equator than the user point, you may want to get the latitudinal distance by using the latitude of the outer point for the two new points.

Comment: The result was pretty much the same. I must be doing something else wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way

```
var region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(userLocation!, MKCoordinateSpanMake(4 * abs(destination.latitude - userLocation!.latitude), 4 * abs(destination.longitude - userLocation!.longitude)))
self.mapView.setRegion(region2, animated: true)
```

I had to play with the multipliers a bit to get the range right - but `MKCoordinateSpanMake` will work on the lat/lon difference, which you do have available.  It looks like you need at least double the calculated angle difference if you want your user location centered, and we should probably do something with finding which of lat/lon is the greater and use that for both.

This should get you moving in the right direction.